# menu not collapsing in navbar-toggle bootstrap

Tags: jquery, navbar

Using HTML5 CSS3 bootstrap and jquery

Bootstrap navbar menu doesn't collapse when browser resized.
I've checked the html and I'm using up to date jquery version

Searched through lots of other posts for ideas and tried a lot of stuff already but no joy

I hope someone can help

Code as follows

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="navDiv" class="navDiv">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navDiv"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="about.html">About the project</a>-->
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-header navDiv">
                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/revive_logo_small.png"></a>-->
            </div>
            <div id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">| Home |</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| Hypno |</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| NLP |</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| Coaching |</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| About June |</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| Contact |</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <img src="images/revive_logo_medium.png" class="me" alt="June">
                    <br>

                </div><!-- end 4 column div -->
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                </div><!-- end 8 column div -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- end full width div -->
    </div>
</div><!--</ content div> -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a class (class="collapse navbar-collapse") on your div-container 'div id="myNavbar"'.
Also you have to change your data-toggle to '#myNavbar', because this div-container contains your menu items.
Furthermore you have to add bootstrap.js as a resource.

It has to look like:

```
<div id="navDiv" class="navDiv">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="about.html">About the project</a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header navDiv">
            <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/revive_logo_small.png"></a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">| Home |</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| Hypno |</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| NLP |</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| Coaching |</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| About June |</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">| Contact |</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/74h6s8ch/)

Comment: Thanks for that, the navbar now collapses but when I click the 3bar menu button it disappears, any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the code i post above?
On JSFiddler it works and the 3bar menu button does not disappears